a href is not working for resume i am trying to view resume using this but it is showing invalid page
i am trying to retrive reusme folder to view resume but it is not showing in my database i have used reumse_path for resume column
 data.forEach(app => {
                    let appHtml = `
                        <div class="application">
                            <h3>Job Title: ${app.job_title}</h3>
                            <p>Candidate Name: ${app.name}</p>
                            <p>Email: ${app.email}</p>
                            <p>Phone: ${app.phone}</p>
                            <p>Cover Letter: ${app.cover_letter}</p>
                            <p>Resume: <a href="${app.resume_path}" target="_blank">View Resume</a></p>
                            <p>Status: ${app.status}</p>
                            <p>Applied At: ${app.applied_at}</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    `;
                    container.append(appHtml);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Failed to load applications:', error);
            }
        });


Does console.log(data) show the expected response?

no it is not showing the response and this is my first project i am working on thats why i am facing issues.

If you're not getting the expected response from the AJAX request, the problem is probably in the server code, not this code you've posted.

okay, i will check my php code for this
